# Convergence in measure implies convergence almost everywhere (on a countable set!)

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, convergence-divergence

Here is an interesting problem from "Real Analysis for Graduate Students" by Richard Bass (which is an amazing book, by the way).

> Suppose $(X, \mathcal{A}, \mu)$ is a measure space, and $X$ is a countable set. Prove that if $f_n$ is a sequence of measurable functions converging to $f$ in measure, then $f_n$ also converges to $f$ a.e. (almost everywhere).

This is Exercise 10.9 in page 79. I tried applying the theorem that if $f_n\to f$ in measure, then $f_n$ has a subsequence $\{f_{n_k}\}$ that converges to $f$ a.e. But I am having trouble using the fact that $X$ is a countable set. I would appreciate a hint in the right direction.

Comment: @Davide Doesn't the proof below additionally assume that the atoms, i.e., the elements of the partition described below, are measurable? Does the result hold if they are not?

Comment: Pedro M. actually explained it to me in detail [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1143440/does-convergence-in-probability-imply-a-s-convergence-in-a-countable-space/1143552?noredirect=1#comment2334752_1143552), sorry to bother you and thanks anyway!

Comment: @Aubrey: No problem! Thanks for linking the new question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assume that $X=\{x_j,j\in\mathbb N\}$ and that $\mu\{x_j\}>0$ for each $j$ and $f=0$, $f_n\geqslant 0$. We have to show that for each $j$, $f_n(x_j)\to 0$ as $n$ goes to infinity.

Fix $j$ and $\varepsilon\gt 0$; for $n$ large enough, we have $\mu\{x,f_n(x)\geqslant\varepsilon\}\lt\mu\{x_j\}$, hence $f_n(x_j)\lt\varepsilon$ for these $n$.

In general, it may be possible that $\{x_j\}$ is not measurable. However, the $\sigma$-algebra on $X$ is generated by a countable partition and each $f_n$ is constant on each element of the partition, hence we can without loss of generality assume that $X=\{x_j,j\in\mathbb N\}$ endowed with the powerset.

This shows the convergence at the points $x_j$ which have positive measure. In a general measure space, we can show that if $f_n\to 0$ in measure and $\{x_0\}  $ has positive measure, then $f_n(x_0)\to 0$. But this does not guarantee the almost everywhere convergence because we cannot remove (as in the case where $X$ is countable) the points $x$ such that the measure of $\{x\}$ is $0$.

Comment: Thank you, Davide! This is a very nice solution. I especially liked your edit, as it clarified where the assumption "$X$ is countable" was used.

Comment: @DavidMitra You are right, I assumed that the $\sigma$-algebra is the power set which does not need to be true. However, in our context, the $\sigma$-algebra is generated by a countable partition, and we can replace the $x_j$ in the answer by an element of the partition.

Comment: @David Sorry, it's not clear to me why the elements of the partition are measurable? (The proof doesn't seem to go through if they are not measurable.)

Comment: Explained [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1143440/does-convergence-in-probability-imply-a-s-convergence-in-a-countable-space/) (just adding this so Davide sees it, in case he hasn't).