# Countable measure space: Convergence in probability implies convergence a. e.

Tags: probability-theory

Can somebody give me a hint for the following exercise, I don't know how to start...

[image]

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does convergence in probability imply a.s. convergence in a countable space?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1143440/does-convergence-in-probability-imply-a-s-convergence-in-a-countable-space)

Answer (score 0):

Some help getting started: define the "bad" sets $B_{n,k} = \{ \omega \in \Omega : |\xi_k(\omega) - \xi(\omega)| > 1/n \}$. Write the definition of convergence in probability and convergence almost everywhere in terms of unions and intersections of the $B_{n,k}$. (This will also help with other problems related to convergence a.e. vs. in probability; for instance this is relevant to Egorov's theorem).

If you show where you got stuck I may be able to give a better hint.